# DOW Mini Futures Options Liquidity - Symbol YM

Tags: options, trading, call-options, put-options

I am trading on the Interactive Brokers TWS platform. That is the name of the broker and the platform they offer that I use. I have noticed that there is almost no liquidity on the YM Mini option contracts. There is plenty of liquidity on the underlying futures exchange, just not for the options.

Am I missing something? Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

After asking this question I just found the DJX which does offer liquidity. The index is 1/100th the value of the DJIA index. It is an options only market.

Comment: How convenient.

Answer (score 0):

No one has interest in trading those options. It is what it is. Many tickers have options that no one trades. If you want liquidity for equity index options, all the liquidity is in the SPY. There are some option liquidity on ES too. QQQ has liquidity. I think IWM does too. That's just the way it is.